# Android - How stop and destroy all videos in adapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

H1, i have my RecyclerView adapter with many elements and among them i have my FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_relative_first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/video_thumb_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</FrameLayout>
```

In my adapter i load thumb and set OnClickListener on my FrameLayout:

```
    if (data.getVideos().size() > 0) {
        holder_all.videos_framelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            final String video_id_all = getVideoId(data.getVideos().get(i));
            String image_url_all = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id_all + "/hqdefault.jpg";
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(image_url_all).into(holder_all.videos_thumbs);
            holder_all.videos_framelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    holder_all.videos_framelayout.setId(position + 1);
                    VideoViewerFragment fragment = VideoViewerFragment.newInstance(video_id_all);
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager myFragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    myFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(position + 1, fragment).commit();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        holder_all.videos_thumbs.setImageBitmap(null);
        Picasso.with(mContext).cancelRequest(holder_all.videos_thumbs);
        holder_all.videos_framelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

And i to face a problem. When user for example click on 2-3 videos it's very bad for memory. How destroy all videos when click on another or if start scroll?

Also my fragment:

```
public class VideoViewerFragment extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    private String video_id;


    public VideoViewerFragment() {}
    private static final String KEY_VIDEO_ID = "KEY_VIDEO_ID";

    public static VideoViewerFragment newInstance(final String videoId) {
        final VideoViewerFragment youTubeFragment = new VideoViewerFragment();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(KEY_VIDEO_ID, videoId);
        youTubeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return youTubeFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        final Bundle arguments = getArguments();

        if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            video_id = bundle.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        } else if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey(KEY_VIDEO_ID)) {
            video_id = arguments.getString(KEY_VIDEO_ID);
        }

        initialize(my key, this);
    }

    public void setVideoId(final String videoId) {
        video_id = videoId;
        initialize("AIzaSyDADUNPwg8ZJ0eYVVCFWoyr07AIa4KF-XM", this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean restored) {
        if (video_id != null) {
            if (restored) {
                youTubePlayer.play();
            } else {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(video_id);
                //youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_id);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
        if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()) {


    youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {}
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    bundle.putString(KEY_VIDEO_ID, video_id);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe play video in other activity?